# Cardinality separable connected metric space

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to show a separable connected metric space has a single point or  $\mathfrak{c}$ points.
I already found the cardinality of a separable metric space is less than or equal to $2^{\aleph_{0}}$ by using a bijection from a separable metric space to $\mathcal{P}(A)^{\mathbb{N}}$ where $A$ is countable dense. However, I don't know how to prove it should have a single point or exactly $\mathfrak{c}$

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be your separable connected metric space and let $x \in X$. You have already done the hard part and proved that the cardinality of $X$ is at most $c$. For the other direction (which doesn't depend on separability), just observe that the function $f : X \to \Bbb{R}$ defined by $f(y) = d(x, y)$ is continuous, and hence its image is connected: but a non-empty connected subset of $\Bbb{R}$ is either a point or an interval and so has cardinality $1$ or $c$.

Answer (score 2):

If your space $X$ has distinct points $a,b$, then the distance function $X\to\mathbb R:x\mapsto d(a,x)$ take the value $0$ at $a$ and a non-zero value at $b$. By connectedness, it must also take all the values between these two.